# Deleting objects using iterator

Tags: c++

I am writing some code for a class project. One of the tasks is to delete a collection of pointers to a class we have created. The solution looks like this:

```
CDocument::~CDocument()
{
    for(std::list<CActor*>::iterator it = mActors.begin(); it != mActors.end(); it++)
    {
        delete *it;
    }

    mActors.clear();

}
```

My solution looked like this:

```
CDocument::~CDocument()
{
    for(std::list<CActor*>::iterator it = mActors.begin(); it != mActors.end(); it++)
    {
        delete **it;
    }
}
```

My confusion stems from dereferencing the iterator. I want to delete the CActor objects from the list. The iterator provides me, in this case, with a pointer to a pointer. Why would I delete the CActor pointer, *it, rather than the actual object in memory, **it? Also, why the additional mActors.clear()?

Comment: I suggest using smart pointers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `delete` operates on pointers, not the object itself or a reference to the object.. For example with the code

```
int* a = new int;
```

you would delete `a` with

```
delete a;
```

not

```
delete *a;
```

As for why `mActors.clear();` is there, it's not strictly necessary since the `std::list` destructor will automatically do the same thing. However if more code is ever added to the destructor, clearing the list ensures all those dangling pointers cannot be accidentally used later.